# rails mongo project which features forking behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, rubygems, mongoid

Using Rails and MongoBD (mongoid) I have a project which users can submit a review for a given place.  Places can have multiple reviews from many people, but another option I was considering was additionally to have a feature whereby a user could "fork" another user's review.  At the basic level it would just be a new review with text copied into it, but I was wondering if anything exists (gem?) that could mimick the git forking behavior, so the fork review is aware of it's parent (basic version control, maybe it even has the option of a pull request to the original owner, etc.)

I use mongoid-history to track versioning for particular reviews, but was wondering if there's anything like what I'm mentioning?

Comment: What's wrong with old plain copying (and storing reference to the source)? Seems a pretty trivial task for me. I think you're getting carried away with git terminology. [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).